# What is the ressource or name of the Android widget: TextView + Circle

Tags: android, android-widget

What is the ressource (`android.R.…`) or name of the following Android widget?

It is neither a `RadioButton` nor an `ExpandableList`.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.kaloer.com/android-preferences read this. If you are talking about the Vibration settings screen it is the PreferenceScreen in the android settings menu. It lets you to create a list of settings with different kinds of preferences such as  CheckBoxPreference,ListPreference,EditTextPreference and so on.
Classes used :

```
import android.preference.CheckBoxPreference;
import android.preference.EditTextPreference;
import android.preference.Preference;
import android.preference.PreferenceCategory;
import android.preference.PreferenceScreen;
import android.preference.Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener;
import android.preference.Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener;
import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;
```

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

it should be an ExpandableList, why this very definition it is that:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html.

Specifically this view is NOT found in the android.R because it doesn't need to be there. Its simply a Special Item that is applied to a ListView that tells the user that this item has children to display.

A snippet from the documentation:

> A view that shows items in a vertically scrolling two-level list. This
>   differs from the ListView by allowing two levels: groups which can
>   individually be expanded to show its children. The items come from the
>   ExpandableListAdapter associated with this view.